# int variable showing incorrect type in column widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, mobile-application

I am trying to not construct a button widget in a condition when `numitems == 0`. `numitems` has type int and initial value of 0.
When I run the program, it shows the button widget even when `numitems == 0`. On debugging, it shows that the type of `numitems` is `Growable list` having size 1.

Here is the code.

```
class BasketPageState extends State<BasketPage> {
    ///////////////
    ////// declare  
    ///////////////
  int numitems = 0; 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    /////////////
    ////// update  
    /////////////
    numitems = 0; 
    basketBloc = BlocProvider.of<BasketBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                BlocListener<BasketBloc,BasketState>(
                  listener: (context,state){
                  },
                  child: BlocBuilder<BasketBloc,BasketState>(
                      builder: (context,state) {
                        return Container();
                      }),
                ),
                   Column(
                     children: [
                       SizedBox(
                         height: 600,
                         child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                         
                  stream: itemsStream,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('Something went wrong');
                          }
                          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return Text("Loading");
                          }
                          if (snapshot.data!.docs.length == 0){
                            return Text("Currently there are no food items in the list");
                          }
                          numitems=0;
                          return ListView(
                            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                              Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                              DateTime expirationDate = data['edate'];
                              final now = DateTime.now();
                              final bool isExpired = expirationDate.isBefore(now);
                              if (isExpired) return Container();
                                
                              /////////////
                              ////// update  
                              /////////////
                              numitems= numitems+1;
                              return ListTile(child: Text(capitalize(data['item_name'])));
                            }).toList(),
                          ); }, ),
                       ),
                       
                         
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        ////// debug showing numitems type as Growable List here  
                        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        
                       this.numitems>0? 
                       Container(
                         child: ElevatedButton(
 
                           child: const Text('Check out'),
                         ),
                       )
                        :Container(),
                     ],),],),),),);
                     }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you include `numitems` declaration ?

Comment: can you include where `numItems` changes?

Comment: Are nitems and numItems same? Provide complete code snippet to find a solution.

Comment: numitems represents number of items. Code snippet is added. Thanks.

Comment: Replaced nitems with numitems. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: On hovering the mouse pointer over `numitems` it shows Growable list. but on using Evaluate expression option in andriod studio, it shows the value to be zero. Now I see that the  button is constructed before the list is populated.